# Creating a list of float values

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

How to create a list of 'x' cosinus values in range from -pi to pi? I have to **not use numpy** or any library except math and matplotlib (the second one to make a graph using these values). For example user inputs a number 1000, the range between -pi and pi is divided into 1000 numbers and then I have to save it to a list and plot a graph. I have no idea how to do it without numpy :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

inp = 1000
step = 2 * math.pi / (inp - 1)
X = [-math.pi + i*step for i in range(inp)]
Y = [math.sin(x) for x in X]
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Oh thanks, it's much easier way than I tried to do it :)